# How can I check that a jQuery chainable functions was called in unit test

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

How check a jQuery chainable functions was called in a unit test. For exemple the follow code

```
function myFunction() {
    var elem = $('#id').removeClass('someClass').addClass('anotherClass');
    return elem;
}
```

How test if removeClass and addClass are called and have the right values. I'm using sinon to stub, but I recive an error.

Comment: Why not just `console.log()`? https://jsfiddle.net/tr_santi/4LugsLdc/ Or, if you want to see the classes attached to the element both before and after the function call, https://jsfiddle.net/tr_santi/4LugsLdc/2/

Comment: I'm writing unit testing, this is why I can't use `console.log`

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in this [blog post](https://coderwall.com/p/fm2ziw/jquery-chain-testing-with-sinonjs) this can be achieved by using two stubs call if `returns` property.

In this case

```
function myFunction() {
    var elem = $('#id').removeClass('someClass').addClass('anotherClass');
    return elem;
}
```

and in this test cenario

```
it('your test case', function(done) {
    var jQueryFunctions = {
        addClass: function(params) {
            assert.equals(params, 'your assertion');
        },
        removeClass: function() {}
    };

    sinon.stub(jQueryFunctions, 'addClass').returns(jQueryFunctions);
    sinon.stub(jQueryFunctions, 'addClass').returns(jQueryFunctions);

    sinon.stub(window, '$').returns(jQueryFunctions);    
});
```

It's very simple and easily.